# Better adjustment to make class inherit different superclass

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `A` that inherit `Middle`, which inherit `OriginBase`

```
public abstract class Base<T>
public class OriginBase<T extends CustomObject> extends Base<T>
public class Middle<T extends CustomObject> extends OriginBase<T>

public class A extends Middle<ObjectA>
public class B extends Middle<ObjectB>
public class C extends Middle<ObjectC>
```

Due to new feature and refactor of class `A`, I got a new version of class `OriginBase`, `NewBase`, which is similar to `OriginBase` and only have a few more methods. The problem is that not only class `A` inherit `Middle`, so I cannot simply change `Middle`'s superclass to `NewBase`.

For now, my solution is to create a new class `NewMiddle` extends `NewBase`, add corresponding new override methods, and then make class `A` extends `NewMiddle`. But this will cause hundreds of lines of code duplication.

To avoid such redundant duplication, I have thought about generics inherit.
The idea is to let class A, B, C specify the `Base` class they needed, such as:

```
public abstract class Base<T>
public class OriginBase<T extends CustomObject> extends Base<T>
public class NewBase<T extends CustomObject> extends Base<T>
public abstract class CommonBase<B extends Base>

// I'm not sure is this a good idea, even not sure if it's a right concept...
public class NewMiddle<B extends Base<T extends CustomObject>, T> extends CommonBase<B, T>

// modified class 
public class A extends Middle<NewBase<ObjectA>>
// other classes
public class B extends Middle<OriginBase<ObjectB>>
public class C extends Middle<OriginBase<ObjectC>>
```

How to achieve this kind of inheritance? Is this a good idea to do so?